# How to tell if a key has been released in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress

I am using this code to test whether a key has been pressed, but I also need a binding that is called when a key is released. If no such binding exists, I would settle for a bit of code that continuously checks if the key is still being pressed.

```
w.bind("<Key>",key)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will call `onkeyrelease` when *any* key is released:

```
w.bind("<KeyRelease>", onkeyrelease)
```

To react to a particular key's release, you would use

```
w.bind("<KeyRelease-key>", onkeyrelease_of_key)
```

where `key` should be replaced by the name of the key.

Comment: This is incomplete info. 1) What does the undefined `onkeyrelease` function do? 2) What is the key-monitoring process? And then, how's `w.bind("<KeyRelease>",onkeyrelease)` different from questioner's `w.bind("<Key>",key)`, which works fine with the right key(event) function?