# How can I detect the amount of time that a button is pressed in python?

Tags: python, time, tk-toolkit, morse-code

I need to make a morse code encoder in python.
Based on the length of time, the key pressed will be a dot (.) or a dash (-).

Ideally I would like this input process to be "running  in the background" so I can do other things in my program in the mean time. I was thinking about using threading, but I think Tk actually does this for me, even though I don't need the graphics capabilities.

Any idea how to get the length of time the key was pressed down?

```
import threading
import Tkinter as tk

def onKeyPress(event):
    print event.char
    print "time =", "????"

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)
root.mainloop()



#class KeyEventThread(threading.Thread):
#    def run(self):
#         your while-loop here
#kethread = KeyEventThread()
#kethread.start()
```

Comment: I'm thinking that threading might actually be the way to go.  If a key is pressed *down* then you'd enter a loop with a counter delay of some sort, maybe 1ms per cycle?, then with each cycle if the key is still pressed you add to the timer, and exit when the key is no longer pressed.

Comment: How about saving start time on press and end time on release of the button?

Comment: Good idea.  There must be a keyup and keydown function, then I can just get the difference between the times.

Comment: Here is the key release bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704179/how-to-tell-if-a-key-has-been-released-in-tkinter Good Luck :0)