# Multiple keystrokes with timestamps

Tags: python, tkinter

So, my project team is trying to code in Python a program that opens a window and shows when you press 1 out of 8 keys in your keyboard, and this program records for how long is it pressed and makes a table and outputs it when the window is closed.

The problem is, since you use event handlers which calls a function when you are or you are not pressing a key, if you press more than one key, since Python is a interpreted language, it can't have two function calls at the same time. How do we constantly keep track of 8 keys being or not being recorded at the same time?

Thanks

Edit: Using Tkinter for GUI

Comment: Half serious answer: due to the relativistic nature of the universe, there's no such thing as "at the same time". If your program records that one key was pressed one nanosecond before another, when you observe them happening at the same time, does it really make that much of a difference?

Comment: …and btw.: the problem is highly related to the GUI framework you're using. Without knowing which one it is, no one can help you.

Comment: In most implementations, key-press events go into a queue, timestamped according to when they were received, and your event loop processes them one at a time.  Restrictions on having two function calls "at the same time" (or, as @Kevin rightly points out, any two events in the universe at the same time) are nothing to do with whether the language is interpreted or not.  If you do some research on responding to key-stroke events, you'll find a whole lot of solutions, Python and non-Python, that will work fine for your application.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704179/how-to-tell-if-a-key-has-been-released-in-tkinter for how to catch key releases, as well as key presses -- this way you'll be able to keep track of what set are currently held in a pressed state.

Answer (score 0):

Most toolkits give different events for key press and key release. Thus, all you need to do is set separate handlers for the press and the release events. On press, update a dictionary, list, database, or whatever, with the key and the time it was pressed. On release, undo that action.

For example, in Tkinter on python 2.x it might look something like this (though this example merely keeps track of when the key was pressed, not how long it was pressed)

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.active = {}
        self.label = tk.Label(self, width=50)
        self.label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        for key in ("a","s","d","f", "h","j", "k", "l"):
            self.active[key] = None
            self.label.bind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, self.on_press)
            self.label.bind("<KeyRelease-%s>" % key, self.on_release)

        self.update_label()
        self.label.focus_set()

    def update_label(self):
        chars = [char for char in self.active.keys() if self.active[char] is not None]
        self.label.configure(text="active keys: " + ",".join(sorted(chars)))

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.active[event.keysym] = event.time
        self.update_label()

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.active[event.keysym] = None
        self.update_label()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```